# Software as a service - Approach

Tags: saas

I have a desktop ERP application used by around 100 customers at different locations.Since its cumbersome to manage deployment and installation of such environment,i am planning to move this to web platform.I came accross this concept of software as service..I intend to go for this design approach...
The challenge i face here is that all customers will have there own databases and i want to make single web application which can connect to all the databases based on some licensing mechanism...
I am not quite sure how to do this.

Feedback and suggestions on this are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The SaaS philosophy is building in two principles. Multi tenant principles and local tenant principles. At first you store user stuff in one database, for second user created new database, for third - created new database and etc. In local tenant option you store all data of all users in one database.
At first - you need a database storage (mysql,msslg, other with) , web aplication for use in browser (buld in php, or html5, of adobe flash(OMG!).
Web application conect  with database - used permission for users and etc.
at simple thats all!

And a have a question in which for you ERP store a users,passwords,documents and other?
Depending on the answer, to look for a solution.